# All ways to partition a string recursively with a minimum length

Tags: java, string, recursion

I stumbled upon this neat recursive function.

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> recursive(String str) {
    System.out.println(str);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (str.length() == 1) {
        result.add(new ArrayList<>());
        result.get(0).add(str);
        return result;
    }

    for (ArrayList<String> list : recursive(str.substring(1, str.length()))) {
        ArrayList<String> append = new ArrayList<>(list);
        String aps = str.substring(0, 1) + append.get(0);

        append.set(0, aps);
        ArrayList<String> add = new ArrayList<>(list);
        String ads = str.substring(0, 1);

        add.add(0, ads);
        result.add(append);
        result.add(add);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It returns if you give it the arg "haus":

```
[[haus], [h, aus], [ha, us], [h, a, us], [hau, s], [h, au, s], [ha, u, s], [h, a, u, s]]
```

Now I can't figure out how to implement a minimum length for each part and don't quite get how the function does it.

If I set a minimum length of 2, my desired output is:

```
[[haus], [aus], [ha, us], [us], [hau], [au]]
```

Can this be accomplished without looping through the results afterwards? Not creating elements that don't fit the minimum in the first place.

Comment: In a recursive algorithm, you have to define a "base case" that tells the recursion when to stop.  In this case, the algorithm starts with the full string, and stops recursing when the current string length is 1.  What happens when you change `if (str.length() == 1) {` to check for length 2 instead?

Comment: already did  that. it removes some strings that have a base len of 1 but not all. the function seems to build the result from bottom up

Comment: The two outputs differ not only in their minimum length. In the first output, all characters are present in each partition list. In your desired output, there are partition lists where some characters are absent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible. But IMHO your algorithm is hard to understand and modify, for these reasons:

- It modifies the content of a list (`append.set(0, aps);`)
- It concatenates strings, so if you skip processing a 1-length string, you break the iteration.

I was not able to change it, so... I rewrote the algorithm my way:

```
static List<List<String>> recursive(String str) {
    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        recursive(list, str, i);
    }
    return list;
}

static void recursive(List<List<String>> list, String str, int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        addToList(stringList, str);
        list.add(stringList);
        return;
    }

    List<List<String>> newList = recursive(str.substring(index));
    String pref = str.substring(0, index);
    for (List<String> ls : newList) {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        addToList(stringList, pref);
        addToList(stringList, ls.toArray(new String[ls.size()]));
        if (!stringList.isEmpty()) {
            list.add(stringList);
        }
    }
}

static void addToList(List<String> list, String... strings) {
    Stream.of(strings)
            .filter(s -> s.length() > 1)
            .forEach(list::add);
}
```

It provides this result for `haus`:

`[[haus], [aus], [us], [au], [ha, us], [hau]]` which is the expected one I think.

---

One last point: filtering out the 1-length strings **afterwards** can be done like this:

```
    List<List<String>> outputList = recursive("haus").stream()
            .map(List::stream)
            .map(stringStream -> stringStream.filter(str -> str.length() > 1))
            .map(stringStream -> stringStream.collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .filter(ls -> !ls.isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```